# Replace alarm (schedule an alarm signal) with sub-seconds alarm (microseconds)

Tags: c, alarm

Currently have some C code that uses sigaction to associate a handler to the SIGALRM signal. 
Now in code the VIDIOCSYNC ioctl on in->fd suspends execution until in->buf has been filled.
Same webcam devices can freewheel, so my app should support such devices without blocking the GUI.

```
#define SYNC_TIMEOUT 5

static int alarms;

static void sigalarm(int signal)
{
    alarms++;
}

static void siginit(void)
{
    struct sigaction act, old;

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_handler = sigalarm;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, &old);
}

void wait_for_frame(input_t *in, int frameid)
{
        alarms = 0;
        alarm(SYNC_TIMEOUT);
        if (ioctl(in->fd, VIDIOCSYNC, in->buf + frameid) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "input: Can't wait for frame %d: %s\n", frameid, strerror(errno));
    }
        if(alarms) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\n"
                        "Your capture card driver: %s\n"
                        "is taking too long to provide frames.  This could be due\n"
                        "either to a broken capture card, a signal that has become unstable\n"
                        "or very noisy, or a driver misconfiguration.\n",
                        in->drivername);
    }
    alarm(0);
}
```

I want to change this with this condition: if no frame arrives within 100 ms, then timeout and give the GUI the chance to update itself.

Comment: AFAICR, the POSIX functions [`setitimer()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setitimer.html) and 
`getitimer()` provide sub-second alarm capability -- particularly `setitimer()`.  If you use ITIMER_REAL, you still get a SIGALRM generated, so you don't have to change other parts of the system.

Comment: Maybe adding `volatile` would help?

Comment: On second thoughts, since `setitimer()` and `getitimer()` are deprecated in favour of [`timer_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_gettime.html) and
[`timer_settime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_settime.html), you should be using these instead.  These use the nanosecond resolution `struct timespec` instead of the microsecond resolution `struct timeval` types.  The nanosecond types are the direction of the future.

Comment: If the variable `alarms` is modified from a signal handler, it should nominally be a variable of type `volatile sig_atomic_t alarms = 0;`, and I'd make it `static` too unless there's a really good reason not to.